# the discretionary of the word `difficult'

Tags: tex-core, discretionary

Is the discretionary of the word *difficult* `di\discretionary{f-}{fi}{ffi}cult` equivalent to `dif\-ficult` (or `dif\discretionary{-}{}{}`)?

Comment: Instead of `dif\-ficult` it's better to use `\hyphenation{dif-ficult}`. Putting the discretionary by hand will break the ffi ligature (which is probably why you are asking this question).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The TeXbook, p. 95

> The most common case of a discretionary break is a simple discretionary hyphen
>
> ```
> \discretionary{-}{}{}
> ```
>
> for which TeX accepts the abbreviation `\-`.

Hence `dif\-ficult` is equivalent to `dif\discretionary{-}{}{}ficult`.

---

You can also see this in the output log:

```
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\setbox0\hbox{dif\-ficult}
\showbox0
\bye
```

```
> \box0=
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x33.6112
.\tenrm d
.\tenrm i
.\tenrm f
.\discretionary
..\tenrm -
.\tenrm ^^L (ligature fi)
.\tenrm c
.\tenrm u
.\tenrm l
.\tenrm t
```

The other variant with `di\discretionary{f-}{fi}{ffi}cult` produces

```
> \box0=
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x33.33342
.\tenrm d
.\tenrm i
.\discretionary replacing 1
..\tenrm f
..\tenrm -
.|\tenrm ^^L (ligature fi)
.\tenrm ^^N (ligature ffi)
.\tenrm c
.\tenrm u
.\tenrm l
.\tenrm t
```

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood `\discretionary`. They are different, the positions of line breaks in these two cases are also different (if the line breaks at the position `\discretionary` appears).